# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCroppedCanvas' of undefined [VueJs]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using **[vue-cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#cropperjs)** library, but when I run the code I am always getting error messages:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCroppedCanvas' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I used the code from here:

```
<template>

  <div id="app">
    <h2 style="margin: 0;">Vue CropperJS</h2>
    <hr/>
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"
           style="font-size: 1.2em; padding: 10px 0;"
           @change="setImage" />
    <br/>
    <div style="width: 400px; height:300px; border: 1px solid gray; display: inline-block;">
      <vue-cropper
          ref='cropper'
          :guides="true"
          :view-mode="2"
          drag-mode="crop"
          :auto-crop-area="0.5"
          :min-container-width="250"
          :min-container-height="180"
          :background="true"
          :rotatable="true"
          :src="imgSrc"
          alt="Source Image"
          :img-style="{ 'width': '400px', 'height': '300px' }">
      </vue-cropper>
    </div>
    <img :src="cropImg" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid gray" alt="Cropped Image" />
    <br/>
    <br />

    <button @click="cropImage" v-if="imgSrc != ''" style="margin-right: 40px;">Crop</button>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  import VueCropper from 'vue-cropperjs';
  export default {
    components: {
      VueCropper,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        imgSrc: '',
        cropImg: '',
      };
    },
    methods: {
      setImage(e) {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file.type.includes('image/')) {
          alert('Please select an image file');
          return;
        }
        if (typeof FileReader === 'function') {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (event) => {
            this.imgSrc = event.target.result;
            // rebuild cropperjs with the updated source
            this.$refs.cropper.replace(event.target.result);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
          alert('Sorry, FileReader API not supported');
        }
      },
      cropImage() {
        // get image data for post processing, e.g. upload or setting image src
        this.cropImg = this.$refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Also, I install the library using NPM.

Where is the problem?
It seems like it does not identify both of functions, but where can I find them? they should already predefined in the library.

Comment: please include the relevant code in your post

Comment: This code is exactly as it appears in your application? You haven't changed anything?

Comment: @thanksd no, it is the same.

Comment: Hmm then your code shouldn't be producing those errors. One thought is that some other error is causing the `<vue-cropper>` component to not load, but you'd almost certainly see another error in your log. Otherwise, are you sure you're not attempting to call those methods anywhere else in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `vue-cropper` is not loaded.

This is just a stab in the dark, and while this *should* be fine, can you try using `VueCropper` in the template instead of `vue-cropper`?